# check for number then replace

Tags: jquery, css

I have an issue. I am checking a specific span class for a number, if the number equals a specific amount- I want to simply swap the number for either a icon or image. I can get the alert to trigger if the number matches, but how do I replace the number for the heart or an image as well as removing the best replies text? and aside from jquery can this be solved with css alone?

Thanks for your help!

```js
var span;
$('span').each(function(){
  if($(this).html() == '199'){
    span = $(this);
    alert("this");
      //$(this).html() == '♥');
  }
});
```

```html
<li id="myMemberStatsBestResponses" class="ms-comm-myMemberStatsItem"><span class="ms-comm-reputationNumbers">199</span> best replies</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the html function to set the content:

```
  $(this).html('♥');
```

jQuery's [html function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) accept as parameter the html value to set into the element that was selected.

Since you want to replace **both** the text of the `span` and the text afterward (which mean - you actually wants to replace the content of the parent `li` element, you can use this:

```js
var span;
$('span').each(function(){
  if($(this).html() == '199'){
    $(this).parent('li').html('♥');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="myMemberStatsBestResponses" class="ms-comm-myMemberStatsItem"><span class="ms-comm-reputationNumbers">199</span> best replies</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the text "best replies" then either you should have a different span OR append it with 199 something like below -

```
<li id="myMemberStatsBestResponses" class="ms-comm-myMemberStatsItem"><span class="ms-comm-reputationNumbers">199 best replies</span></li>
```

JQuery should then look like this -

```
var span;
$('span').each(function(){
  if($(this).html() == '199 best replies'){
    span = $(this);
    alert("this");
    $(this).html('♥');
  }
});
```

Comment: Right. But the requirement was also to remove the text 'best replies' I believe. Would your answer remove that text as well ? If the user doesn't want to remove that text, then your answer is correct. I still Vote Up your answer as you have corrected the syntax. :)